# Spring 3.0 unable to forward request from HandlerInterceptorAdapter

Tags: spring, interceptor, spring-3

I want to redirect to home page if session get invalid.
My spring-servlet.xml is

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" />
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
        <bean class="com.xxx.MyInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Interceptor :

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        if ((null == request.getSession(false))
                || (null == request.getSession(false).getAttribute(
                        "user"))) {
            System.out.println("user logged out...");
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("loginForm.htm");
            rd.forward(request, response);
            return false;
        }
        return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }
```

But its not working...
Whenever application get started, the message get printed multiple times and at the end it gives stack overflow..

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the problem is in your mapping path. Since its mapped with `/**` your loginForm.htm is also getting intercepted. You have two solutions available to resolve this problem.

Either define `<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />` so that the *.htm requests will not be intercepted. Replace the location and mapping values as per your path where the *.htm files are.

And another option is to change your mapping in intercepter with something like `/*.do` or something else.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Comment: thanx for the reply,but the requirement is, i hv to intercept each request for checking if session is valid or not.. if not then redirect to main page... all url pattern ends with .htm

Comment: That is what I have tried to explain since all your request mappings end with *.htm you are getting into an infinite loop. There must be some exlusion from this pattern other wise your problem will persist. :-)

Comment: Thankx for the direction... Solved problem by changing LoginForm.htm to LoginForm.do and interceptor mapping from "/**" to "/*.htm"..