# Interceptor preHandle() not redirecting to login.html

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-security, redirect

I have a spring application. I introduced a sessionInterceptor to prevent direct access to index.jsp. If the user is not logged in it shouldn't be able to access index.jsp and should be redirected to login.html. The code is hitting the preHandle() method and running all the code but after `return false` it's not redirecting to login.html. What's wrong? Any gurus out there for help? Thanks in advance.

My preHandle() in SessionInterceptor.java is:

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        // if displaying the home page, make sure the user is reloaded.
        if (request.getRequestURI().endsWith("login.html")) {
            session.removeAttribute("isUserLoggedIn");
        }

        if (session.getAttribute("isUserLoggedIn") == null && !request.getRequestURI().endsWith("login")) {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.html");
            return false;               
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I have tried the following as well but all in vain.

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/login.html");
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

My dispatcher-servlet.xml settings are:

```
<bean id="sessionInterceptor" class="com.xxx.xxx.xxx.SessionInterceptor" />
<bean id="annotationMapper" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="sessionInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Configures Handler Interceptors -->
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" />
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
        <bean class="com.xxx.xxx.xxx.SessionInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

The web.xml is:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: If it's not redirecting, what is it doing?

Comment: It's doing nothing. After running the full code. It stays on the same page.

Comment: What page is that? If you open your browser's network console, what does the response contain?

Comment: `Request URL:http://localhost:8080/myContext/index.jsp
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK`

The response is my index.jsp.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132653/spring-3-0-unable-to-forward-request-from-handlerinterceptoradapter

Answer (score 2):

you can try redirecting to a logical path that will be catched from a controller
Try

```
response.sendRedirect("/NotLogged");
```

And then create a function like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/NotLogged"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String notLogged() {
    return "login.html";
}
```

I hope it will work for you!

Comment: `response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/errors/401.html");`

Answer (score 0):

When i use return false, i take "Error: Exceeded maxRedirects. Probably stuck in a redirect loop http://localhost:8080/api/login"

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    if(true){
        response.sendRedirect("/api/login");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```