# Validate user per every request and response in spring

Tags: java, spring, authentication, controller

Since I am new to Spring and i have an issue with user service. I have admin panel and customer blog. When the Customer is logged into browser, the admin has been changed the status to Active from InActive in Table of Customer. But the user session is active. So that he can able to do process after the status is changed.

I need one common method that should be in common place. This method should be access the table and validate the user per every request. I have one controller and that should invoke the common method. Because I cannot edit code to every class. In JSP & Servlet I have handled this using doFilter. How to achieve this in Spring..

AppInitializer.java

```
import javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}

@Override
protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
    registration.setMultipartConfig(getMultipartConfigElement());
}

private MultipartConfigElement getMultipartConfigElement() {
    MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement = new MultipartConfigElement( LOCATION, MAX_FILE_SIZE, MAX_REQUEST_SIZE, FILE_SIZE_THRESHOLD);
    return multipartConfigElement;
}

private static final String LOCATION = "C:/temp/"; // Temporary location where files will be stored

private static final long MAX_FILE_SIZE = 5242880; // 5MB : Max file size.
                                                    // Beyond that size spring will throw exception.
private static final long MAX_REQUEST_SIZE = 20971520; // 20MB : Total request size containing Multi part.

private static final int FILE_SIZE_THRESHOLD = 0;

}
```

AppConfig.java

```
import javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}

@Override
protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
    registration.setMultipartConfig(getMultipartConfigElement());
}

private MultipartConfigElement getMultipartConfigElement() {
    MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement = new MultipartConfigElement( LOCATION, MAX_FILE_SIZE, MAX_REQUEST_SIZE, FILE_SIZE_THRESHOLD);
    return multipartConfigElement;
}

private static final String LOCATION = "C:/temp/"; // Temporary location where files will be stored

private static final long MAX_FILE_SIZE = 5242880; // 5MB : Max file size.
                                                    // Beyond that size spring will throw exception.
private static final long MAX_REQUEST_SIZE = 20971520; // 20MB : Total request size containing Multi part.

private static final int FILE_SIZE_THRESHOLD = 0;

}
```

HibernateConfiguration.java

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "com.ppts.configuration" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class HibernateConfiguration {

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.ppts.model" });
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
 }

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
    return properties;        
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
   HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
   txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
   return txManager;
}
}
```

AppController.java

```
package com.sample.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationTrustResolver;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import com.sample.handler.FileHandler;
import com.sample.model.Address;
import com.sample.model.Employee;
import com.sample.model.EmployeeDocument;
import com.sample.model.EmployeeSalary;
import com.sample.model.FileBucket;
import com.sample.model.User;
import com.sample.model.UserProfile;
import com.sample.service.EmployeeDocumentService;
import com.sample.service.EmployeeSalaryService;
import com.sample.service.EmployeeService;
import com.sample.service.UserProfileService;
import com.sample.service.UserService;
import com.sample.validators.FileValidator;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
@SessionAttributes("roles")
public class AppController {

@Autowired
UserService userService;

@Autowired
EmployeeService employeeService;

@Autowired
EmployeeSalaryService employeeSalaryService;

@Autowired
UserProfileService userProfileService;

@Autowired
EmployeeDocumentService employeeDocumentService;

@Autowired
FileValidator fileValidator;

@InitBinder("fileBucket")
protected void initBinderFileBucket(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(fileValidator);
}

@Autowired
MessageSource messageSource;

@Autowired
PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices persistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices;

@Autowired
AuthenticationTrustResolver authenticationTrustResolver;

@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/list" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String adminPage(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("home",true);
    model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
    return "home";
}

@RequestMapping(value = { "/userList" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listUsers(ModelMap model) {
    List<User> users = userService.findAllUsers();
    model.addAttribute("users", users);
    model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
    return "userslist";
}

@RequestMapping(value = { "/newuser" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String newUser(ModelMap model) {
    User user = new User();
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    model.addAttribute("edit", false);
    model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
    return "registration";
}

@RequestMapping(value = { "/newuser" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult result,
        ModelMap model) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "registration";
    }
    if(!userService.isUserSSOUnique(user.getId(), user.getSsoId())){
        FieldError ssoError =new FieldError("user","ssoId",messageSource.getMessage("non.unique.ssoId", new String[]{user.getSsoId()}, Locale.getDefault()));
        result.addError(ssoError);
        return "registration";
    }
    userService.saveUser(user);
    model.addAttribute("success", "User " + user.getFirstName() + " "+ user.getLastName() + " registered successfully");
    model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
    return "registrationsuccess";
}

@RequestMapping(value = { "/edit-user-{ssoId}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String editUser(@PathVariable String ssoId, ModelMap model) {
    User user = userService.findBySSO(ssoId);
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    model.addAttribute("edit", true);
    model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
    return "registration";
}

@RequestMapping(value = { "/edit-user-{ssoId}" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult result,
        ModelMap model, @PathVariable String ssoId) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "registration";
    }
    userService.updateUser(user);
    model.addAttribute("success", "User " + user.getFirstName() + " "+ user.getLastName() + " updated successfully");
    model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
    return "registrationsuccess";
}

//Update User and Employee By Id
@RequestMapping(value = { "/getUserById" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getUserSSOId(ModelMap model) {
    User user = new User();
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    model.addAttribute("edit", true);
    model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
    return "userview";
}

@RequestMapping(value = { "/updateByUserId" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getByUserId( @ModelAttribute User userDetails,ModelMap model,BindingResult result) {
    User user =userService.findBySSO(userDetails.getSsoId());
    if(user!=null){
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("edit", true);
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        return "registration";
    }else{
        FieldError referenceIdError =new FieldError("user","ssoId",messageSource.getMessage("non.empty.userid.notexist", new String[]{userDetails.getSsoId()}, Locale.getDefault()));
        result.addError(referenceIdError);
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        return "userview";
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = { "/updateByUserId" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateUserById(@Valid User user, BindingResult result,
        ModelMap model) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "registration";
    }
    userService.updateUser(user);
    model.addAttribute("success", "User " + user.getFirstName() + " "+ user.getLastName() + " updated successfully");
    model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
    return "registrationsuccess";
}

@RequestMapping(value = { "/deleteByUserId" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String deleteUserById(ModelMap model) {
    User user = new User();
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    model.addAttribute("delete", true);
    model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
    return "userview";
}

@RequestMapping(value = { "/deleteUserById" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String deleteByuserId( @ModelAttribute User userDetails,ModelMap model,BindingResult result) {
    User user=userService.findBySSO(userDetails.getSsoId());
    if(user!=null){
        userService.deleteUserBySSO(userDetails.getSsoId());
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        model.addAttribute("employeeSuccess", "Employee " + user.getFirstName() + " deleted successfully");
        return "registrationsuccess";
    }else{
        FieldError referenceIdError =new FieldError("employee","employeeReferenceId",messageSource.getMessage("non.empty.userid.notexist", new String[]{userDetails.getSsoId()}, Locale.getDefault()));
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        result.addError(referenceIdError);
        return "userview";
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Include your code.

Comment: Branislav Lazic. Added my code and configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make create a class implementing Spring's HandlerInterceptor interface. Its preHandle method will be called for every request before request is processed by the Controller method.

Since you just want to process validation check for each request before it is handled, you can create a class extending the HandlerInterceptorAdapter class which provides convenient defaults for all methods in the HandlerInterceptor interface.

You only need to provide implementation as per your business rule for the following method

```
preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
```

Sample code below

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

public class TransactionInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {
        // Your business logic goes here

        // return true or false depending on whether you want the controller to handle the request or terminate request processing.
    }
}
```

You would need to register the interceptor in Spring Config as below

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    .....
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new YourNewInterceptor());
    }
    .....

}
```

Comment: In controller how i should call this class

Comment: You do not need to call this class explictly in the Controller, the preHandle method will be invoked by Spring before transferring control to the Controller and executing it.

Comment: Here i have one doubt. I have written the code to access the Table to get whether the user is active or not. But i need to redirect the home page if user is not active. Else it should allow the normal process. Can i achieve with UserLogInService

Comment: @MuthuVikki You can find a somewhat related query here which should answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990378/interceptor-prehandle-not-redirecting-to-login-html

Comment: How to call service from Interceptor. Am getting null pointer exception. Is there any way to add some annotation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139781/discussion-between-notionbit-and-muthu-vikki).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that also in `Filter`. You just have to annotate it with `@Component` and voila. It becomes a Spring bean. Like this:

```
@Component
public class UserFilter implements Filter{
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        User user = (User)request.getAttribute("user");
        // Do whatever you want with your user
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```